# Output Custom Image Field in Drupal 7

Tags: file, drupal-7, filenames

I created a custom Image Field in drupal 7 and now want to output it (the url and filename of it (complete filename)).

I tried this :-

```
echo $node->field_featured_image['und'][0]['filename']
```

but it doesn't work :(

Could you help me please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this; seems to work

```
 $image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_featured_image');
            echo file_create_url($image[0]['uri']);
```

But it also shows a URL when there is no image. Thought it should be empty.